# Добавить методы в конструктор

Tags: javascript, конструктор

Добрый день, объясните пожалуйста почему я не могу создать метод *sum* в конструкторе *Constructor* с помощью другого метода *addMethod*.

```
var Constructor = function () {

    this.addMethod = function (name, func) {
       this.name = func;
    }

};

var obj = new Constructor;

obj.addMethod('sum', function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Comment: хотя бы потому, что ты не добавил метод `addMethod`, ты объявил **локальную функцию**, которая не видна извне

Comment: а как вообще должна работать `addMethod`? Как ты хочешь вызывать метод `sum`? он должен добавиться у конкретного объекта `obj`?

Comment: Да поправил, благодарю. Я бы хотел, чтобы все объекты типа Constructor имели метод sum.

Comment: _Я бы хотел, чтобы все объекты типа Constructor имели метод sum_ - тогда ты принял неверный ответ, и решение у тебя так же неверное: ты добавляешь метод только **в текущий** объект, все остальные экземпляры будут без этого метода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что синтаксис не правильный. Нужно использовать this, и вычисляемые свойства для объекта оборачиваются в []
Правильно вот так:

```js
var Constructor = function () {
  this.addMethod = function(name, func) {
    this[name] = func;
  }
};

var obj = new Constructor;

obj.addMethod('sum', function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

console.log(obj.sum(2,2));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: на самом деле это не **вычисляемое** свойство, а _скобочная нотация_